# Keyboard control of collapse/expand triangles in the List view

Tags: keyboard, finder, keybindings

I’ve got a long list of folders in a folder on my Mac. In the List view of Finder, folders are displayed collapsed or expanded by the ▶︎ or ▼ sign on the left side respectively.

[image: screenshot of folders in the List view]

I am wondering if there is a way to expand and collapse these folders using the keyboard as it is quite slow to click them all using a mouse. Moreover, is there a command to expand/collapse all folders in the current view? Unfortunately, I have not found such an option in Finder’s main menu.

Comment: Excellent wording and picture. This will help bring people to the main Q&A covering this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a folder is selected in the List view, press:

- <kbd>←</kbd> to fold (collapse) it,
- <kbd>→</kbd> to unfold (expand) it.

If multiple folders are selected concurrently, all of them will be (un)folded.

See also:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/158748/90319
- https://www.alvinpoh.com/how-to-use-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-expand-or-collapse-all-folders-in-mac-finder/